# google sign-in for android, token expires, Authenticate with a backend server

Tags: android, authentication, token, google-signin

I integrated google sign-in into my project, and Authenticate with a backend server. 
I followed the sample code provided by google.

Here is the code to init google api client:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(Constants.GoogleSignIn.SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
                .build();

        // Build GoogleAPIClient with the Google Sign-In API and the above options.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context.getApplicationContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

And here is the code to fetch google sign in result:

```
private void handleSignInResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result)
{
    BHLog.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess())
    {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        if (acct != null)
        {
            String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
            Managers.getLoginManager().loginWithGoogle(idToken);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (listener != null)
        {
            listener.onGoogleLoginFailed();
        }
    }
}
```

Almost same as google sample code.

The problem is yesterday I got the token in this way and the token was valid. Today I fetched the token still in this way but it was invalid. 
The tokens today and yesterday are the same. I think the token expired yesterday and today I would get a new token, but I still got the same one.

Then I used another device and fetched the token. I got a new one and it was valid.

So the condition is weird. Different devices got different tokens. Using the same device always got the same token, even after one day.

Anyone has ideas about this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: I have same issue. I get same JWT (token id) every time, even after the first token expires. Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should have correct time and date on your device. If you have not, you will pass not valid exp time.

Answer (score 0):

By default, access tokens has validity for 1 hour which seems sufficient to authorize sign in user's data. After you have verified the token with backend server we have to establish a session for user.